# why Ruby String each_char method prints an extra % at the end

Tags: ruby

I'm a Ruby newbie, I tried to print each char in a Ruby string, using

```
"hello world".each_char {|c| print c}
```

However, when I ran the .rb program, it printed out hello world%, with a % character at the end. Then I switched to irb, it worked fined without the extra % character. Can anyone tell me how this happened? Why there was a %?

Comment: That sounds like a shell issue.

Comment: `%` is printend by some terminals to denote a missing newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the program is doing what is expected.
the % is actually the shell prompt.
guessing you do something like:

```
%my-script.rb
hello world%
```

because you don't have a new line, when the output finishes the script just takes control back and shows the prompt